# Error trying to upload file via FTP with C #

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I send to my method the model and a file that I want to save in a specific path, but I get the following error:

> Could not find file 'C:\img\iis2.png' : C\\Program Files (x86)\img\iis2.png

I already tried several examples that I found on the web, but so far nothing has worked for me

```
string path= @"..\img\";
```

code:

```
public ActionResult Guardar_registro(Models.CascadingModelLevantamiento model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        try
        {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpURI + "/" +
                                Path.GetFileName(fileName));
                    WebRequest ftpRequest = WebRequest.Create(ftpURI);
                    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
                    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx@xxxx", "xxxx*");
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path + fileName);
                    FileStream fileStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();
                    int bufferLength = 2048;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
                    Stream uploadStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                    int contentLength = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    while (contentLength != 0)
                    {
                        uploadStream.Write(buffer, 0, contentLength);
                        contentLength = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    }
                    uploadStream.Close();
                    fileStream.Close();
                    request = null;
    }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Hubo un error";
            return View("../Levantamiento/Levantamiento");
        }
```

}

I'm a little new to this, but if someone could support me to solve the mistake

Comment: Please remove your password from the Credentials line. Also can you provide the code you are using when you call the method Guardar_registro()

It looks like your path may be incorrect so you should double check it.

Comment: ready add the route

Comment: @servvs "Please remove your password" - that's not bad advice in general, but kind of pointless here, given that the edit history is public: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57913294/revisions (just FYI, in case you weren't aware).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. @Morquecho It may be best to change your password at this point.

Comment: ready change what I was asked

Comment: Where are you instantiating the fileName and path variables? What is the exact path of the program and the exact path of the image?

Answer (score 1):

I'm too new to comment asking for clarification on what actually sets `fileName` but the error states what's up - the file doesn't exist where it's being tasked to look.

Assuming the file does exist where you want it - you're likely looking for something within [System.IO.Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netframework-4.8)

Add `using System.IO;` at the top of your class file to use any of these.

If it's in a subfolder within the location of your executable, you want something like: `Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "img", fileName);`

If it's in a specific folder like `C:\img\iis2.png`, you want something like `Path.Combine("C:\img", "iis2.png");`

There's a few examples on the [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) page.

Comment: if I am already using System.IO.Path, as for Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() if I do not understand wrong is where I declare my Path?

Comment: [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=netframework-4.8) is the working path of where your executable resides.

Comment: ok, I already changed it but I got the same error: "Could not find file 'C:\\ProgramFiles(x86)\\img_test.png'.": "C:\\ProgramFiles(x86\\img_test.png ""

Comment: You have trailing slashes in your path. `Path.Combine` adds them for you, remove those.

ie: `Path.Combine(@"C:\Program Files (x86)", "img_test.png");`